# Should Users with only 1 reputation (Or with only 1 question/answer) be deleted after 30 days without a login?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should Users with only 1 reputation be deleted after 30 days without a login?  Because It would keep the site cleaner and There must be hundreds - thousands Of dead users that did use their account for only one day, and must of forget their password or something.  Now, there are some users who have more than 1 reputation but it is from only 1 answer.  Like they have 25, one up vote, and one approve answer, I think these users need to be deleted.  This is a kinda bad example, but I didn't need to go hunting for this user also. [Abound](https://askubuntu.com/users/77115/abound) Is a dead user but he/she isn't registered also.  Should I up voted them? Should I accepted their answer?  Do you see my problem?  I don't want to give them reputation if they are dead, they only have one of them, and should be deleted.

Answer (score 13):

> It would keep the site cleaner

I don't see that abandoned accounts really get in the way of anything important. The site is about questions and their answers. If you want to faff around on the `/users/` pages, that's fair enough but that's not the site goal.

> Should I up voted them? Should I accepted their answer? Do you see my problem?

You shouldn't be making any voting decisions based on *who* writes a post. Posts should be voted for on their own merits. User reputation is meaningless when it comes to the content of the post.

If a post answers your question, you should vote for it and accept it. If it doesn't, explain why (other people can see it even if that account has been abandoned) and if poor enough, vote against it.

If you're voting to "give them reputation", you're doing it wrong.
 **Vote to indicate which posts are *best*.**

Comment: Yea but Accepting them will also give me 2 reputations.

Comment: @Andrew 2 reputation is small enough not to encourage you to accept an answer just for the sake of getting rep. But it is enough, to encourage to accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: @Dan for me it is!

Comment: @Andrew So abandoned accounts are bad but accepting answers that didn't help is okay? I think you have it the wrong way around.

Comment: @Oli I know, but I can't help my shelf....  I was just joking,  If the answer is bad, or very low quility this I wouldn't accepted them, all thou, if I don't get a new answer in mouths than I will accpted the best one, if it wasn't vrey poor quility or just bad.

Comment: @Andrew please only accept an answer if it _answers your question_. If no answers do so, then you shouldn't accept any of them. If you want the 2 rep so badly, just go and improve another post, that will get you 2 rep without fraudulent behavior (such as accepting an answer that did not solve your problem).

Comment: @terdon but clicking on a button is ezer than thanking on something.  I am bad at langage Arts.

Comment: @Andrew I don't understand how thanking came into this. You give thanks by accepting/upvoting yes, but you should only accept an answer that solved your problem. If it helped or was useful, upvote it. Also, editing is not only about language, many posts need editing to improve the formatting as well. _Please_ don't accept answers that did not solve your issue, that is abusive behavior. The next poor sap to come along will think that the answer worked for you and will try it and will end up at best confused and at worst with a broken system. **Only accept answers that answered your question**.

Comment: @terdon Yea, but If there isn't going to be a next answer like it havn't goten any new answers in 6 months than ...  I am going to choose the best one, unless there is none, or there all just very low quity.

Comment: @Andrew again, **please don't**. If that's the way you will use the site, I would ask you to not ask questions. You never know when someone might answer your question, it could happen years from now or it could never happen at all. That's irrelevant. You should still only accept answers that answer your question.

Comment: Okay I will take you advice.